# UIInterfaceOrientation animation not working in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation

I have created a Single View application with allow all the interface orientation. In iOS 7 & 8 interface orientation animation is working fine but in the iOS 9 orientation animation is like flick for all the view controller while we rotate the device.

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Comment: are you using storyboards?

Comment: No, adding view controller on Navigation controller.

Comment: Able to resolve, remove main interface as main storyboard in general tab of target setting.

Comment: That was my next question.   It seems like a bug to me - if you replace the window.rootViewController in code - it should forward the rotation events to the new viewcontroller - but it doesn't seem to work right.

Comment: yes agree @Todd, its seems like bug in iOS 9, still checking apple documentation for if i remove main interface are they have any problem during submission on apple store.

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue if you aren't using storyboards --- it's valid to build apps without them.